# WhatsApp - last seen not correct

Tags: whatsapp, nokia-lumia-920

I have a **Nokia Lumia 920** with the latest WhatsApp application.
Sometimes it happens that **my** *last seen* is wrong.

For example, once a friend of mine checked my *last seen* at 20:10 on his phone, and WhatsApp reported that my last access was @ 20:08. I am sure it cannot be possible because I was next to him, talking.

I am sure that there are no web browsers logged in my whatsapp, too.

What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens when your phone is in Battery Saver mode. Most background processes are closed off so sometimes Whatsapp shows the wrong last seen. I've seen it on my phones too